# What does it mean to cross a scalar with a vector in a 2D plane?

Tags: mathematics, physics, vector

At the moment, I'm following [this page](http://www.myphysicslab.com/collision.html) to create a physics engine.

As per that page, I need to cross angular velocity by a distance vector to get relative torque and such, but I'm not sure how (in a 2D plane), you can cross a scalar(angular velocity), and a vector(such as the distance vector). I've assumed so far that you multiply the magnitude, but obviously this isn't correct, as I continue the debugging of my flimsy code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is not defined between a vector and a scalar, so it means nothing (it would be a malformed operation, or perhaps a mis-interpretion of a simple vector scaling operation).

In the link you provided, [angular velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) is a *vector* when it is used in the equation that involves its presence as an operand of the cross product:

> Here we are regarding the angular velocity as a *3 dimensional vector*
>   perpendicular to the plane, so that the *cross product is calculated as*

(Emphasis mine.)

This is in the section "Physics of Collision for Rigid Bodies in 2 Dimensions."